# How could I to highlight code blocks in Scully?

Tags: prismjs, highlightjs, scully

I'm creating a blog with [Scully](https://scully.io/) and looking for a good way to setup code highlight there.

for example, such block of code(with defining the language):

````
```typescript
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BlogComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, BlogRoutingModule, ScullyLibModule],
})
export class BlogModule {}
.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are two ways now:

1. Use **highlight.js** that is included in the library. You just need to activate it in Scully config:

```js
setPluginConfig('md', { enableSyntaxHighlighting: true });
```

2. [Scully Docs](https://scully.io/docs/learn/utilities/syntax-highlighting/prism-js/) suggest using **Primsjs** by installing it and including to your project.

It looks like Scully team wants to get rid of core dependency for **highlight.js** and that's why it's wise to use the second option.